# How to show a list of sites the current user can access?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm working on MOSS 2007 and I want to build a sharepoint webpart that can list all the sites (in the same SPfarm) visible to the current user. What I can think of is:

1. Use FullTextSqlQuery class to search for the sites, but is it possible;
2. Build an external application that crawls the user-sites information by using the Sharepoint Object-Model. The webpart can then use this information.

Is there any simple solution?

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look here: [Talk to SharePoint Through its Web Services](http://www.sharepointmonitor.com/2007/01/sharepoint-web-service/) at "Example 3"

You'll need to write some managed (.net) code.

Comment: Thanks for your link. Please give me some time to digest the materals.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint creates site maps by default. Unless you have turned this off, you can get one from a site by appending `/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx` to the site URL.

Comment: Thank you. This approach only gives me a list of direct subsites, whether or not I have access to. What I want is all the sites within a SPFarm I can access. Any ideas?